# Xdebug stopped working, where do I look for errors?

Tags: php, ubuntu, response, xdebug

I installed Xdebug and all was fine, until suddenly it stopped working. phpinfo() gives a nice XDebug output with all variables.

```
php -m | grep deb
```

also gives twice XDebug (for Zend and PHP), so again looks just fine. My php.ini has these lines:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so
;extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

And yet, when running this code with should check XDebug (from Netbeans docs) it's just stuck. So No IDE is working with XDebug.

```
<?php
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 9001;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die('Unable to bind');
socket_listen($sock);
$client = socket_accept($sock);
echo "connection established: $client";
socket_close($client);
socket_close($sock);
```

Also, according to XDebug installation, I went twice throught the steps. What is wrong with my config? Thanks.

Comment: even after adding xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log" and restarting Apache2, and running an app the log is empty...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At the end, left with only two solutions - to reinstall the Ubuntu OS or to install a new VM especially for xdebug, I'm going for the second one.
Funny thing is, everything was working according to the "RTM" (f=freaking). One thing that I couldn't figure out is how to read the logs for XDebug in order to understand where the real problem is.

## UPDATE

After some struggling, I deleted every single line related to xdebug from every php.ini that I had. And moved these lines to /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini. Restarted Apache, and then PHPStorm, and it works. 
P.S. in the middle, I tried to install xdebug with pecl, from github, and the standard Ubuntu version. I think the one that I compiled is currently working. And.. the log gets updated as well.

```
;xdebug configuration
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

Answer (score 12):

On your server, try this command:

`$ netstat -anp | grep CLOSE_WAIT`

Any :9000 entries will give you XDebug troubles; consider `kill -9 <pid>`.

Comment: For those not completely familiar with linux, the PID on ubuntu for me using this command was the last column: 3131/apache2   PID = 3131

Comment: I know it's an old post , but I had to use sudo with netstat to see the <pid> .
There is already a warning : 

(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too on Ubuntu after updating php.  For me, turning on html errors in php.ini got xdebug with Netbeans to work again ...

```
sudo vi /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
display_errors = On
html_errors = On
```

And restart apache:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9592364&postcount=14

Answer (score 1):

I checked my

> netstat -anp

output and found out that there were number of open sockets (in XDebug port range) by master process on my remote machine [running xDebug].

> Killing the 'master' process solved the problem for me.

Seemed like a port overrun situation for me.
Thought the information might be useful to some.

Answer (score 0):

check port is not occupied, check netbeans is configured to listen to that port(i see you have 9001, 9000 is default usually)also when i debug with eclipse i have to "terminate and relaunch" the debug session every now and then since it stops working, never under stood why, i suspect some sort of expired debug session

Answer (score 0):

Check are you putting breakpoints to the right file. Find first file where script enters (front controller). On symfony there can be more than one for example.

Answer (score 0):

In my case after update xdebug to 3 version I just put/set php.ini config

```
error_reporting=E_ALL
display_startup_errors=1
display_errors=1
```

and then command `php -v` show all warnings and errors.
In my case:

```
Xdebug: [Config] The setting 'xdebug.remote_enable' has been renamed, see the upgrading guide at https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide#changed-xdebug.remote_enable (See: https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-CHANGED)
```